# I Want to add content loading progress bar in before pdf view with (live horizontal progress) in asynctask method

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar, progressdialog, live

How to implement horizontal progress-bar `Contentloadingprogessbar` **Live progress** show please help  me if anybody know this ,
Here the piece of Code I've been added

```
 class RetrievePDFStream extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream> {

 
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        
    }
    @Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {

            URL urlx = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlx.openConnection();
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return inputStream;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
        pdfView.fromStream(inputStream).load();
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onPreExecute()` -> initialize your `ProgressBar` and show/start.

`onPostExecute()` -> hide/stop the `ProgressBar` after `pdfView.fromStream(inputStream).load();`

```
<ProgressBar
     android:indeterminateOnly="true" 
     style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

EDIT:

Further investigation of the pdfviewer library it seems to have an `onLoad()` method.

```
.fromStream(inputStream).onLoad(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
                // hide/stop progress bar.
            }
        }).load();
```

this is more the official way to do it. There doesn't seem to be a way to get the actual progress of the load, being its a stream it would be more involved.

Comment: I try this but horizontal progress bar not fill I try Runnable method but after fill horizontal bar again fill ( I want fill horizontal bar and show pdf Exact Reder process show in horizontal bar)

Comment: Did you initialize/add your progressbar properly? It would be nice, if you could post your progressbar code.